# Set up rtl8723bs SDIO card

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, arch-linux

I am trying to set up rtl8723bs SDIO wi-Fi card on 3.17.2 kernel. I've compile and install driver like [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2249936).

> `grep -i cfg8 .config
>   CONFIG_CFG80211=y
>    # CONFIG_CFG80211_DEVELOPER_WARNINGS is not set
>    # CONFIG_CFG80211_REG_DEBUG is not set
>    # CONFIG_CFG80211_CERTIFICATION_ONUS is not set
>   CONFIG_CFG80211_DEFAULT_PS=y
>   CONFIG_CFG80211_DEBUGFS=y
>    # CONFIG_CFG80211_INTERNAL_REGDB is not set
>   CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT=y`

I am using fresh ubuntu kernel config from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/configs/trusty/). I've disable some unused options...

I see no errors in dmesg from inserted wi-fi driver. Also I see wlan0 interface in the system with `ip link` command. I can set up the interface but seems that it doesn't support Wi-Fi cause I can't see any  phy device with `iw list`.

`rfkill` say nothing. It is a VOYO a1 mini tablet and seems that it has no harware Wi-Fi lock button.

I can't understand what I am doing wrong((

Comment: The easiest way I've found to install Ubuntu on devices with the RTL8723bs is by using Ian Morrison's shellscript after installation of 14.04 LTS. Info is here: https://plus.google.com/+IanMORRISON/posts/UNWdwRMqy3j

Comment: On that that time there are no way to run rtl8723bs Wi-Fi in i386 environment. I don't have any troubles with x86_64 kernel....

Answer (score 0):

Seems that main problem was in disabled hardware counters( Intel remove them from kernel). Without those system was unstable.

Comment: Does it seem to be the case